# Using SAP or PCL in Xamarin Forms Travelling Application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hi I want to use TravelPort API Sample Application(C# Console Application) in my Xamarin Forms Project but I am not able to use namespaces like System.Configuration and System.Service Model in my PCL project.

Later I came to know that I should use DI(Dependency Injection) in my PCL project to use these namespaces. Then I started learning DI.

My question is that I am targeting Android Platform only in my Xamarin Forms project.And I just want to use Flight Search and Flight Booking features from TravelPort Sample App.

So is it convenient to use Shared Application Project rather than a Portable Class Library Project? And Will I be able to use System.Configuration and System.ServiceModel namespaces easily in SAP ?

Comment: Question has been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990307/xamarin-shared-projects-vs-portable-class-libraries

Comment: I would recommend to take advantage over the `netstandard` library instead. https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/